# Ext JS Splitter Color (SASS, 4.2.2)

Tags: extjs, sass, extjs4.2

Having tried just about everything Im at a loss how to change the color of splitter bars using SASS for Ext JS 4.2.2 - they always appear as a white bar.

Say I have a hbox or vbox layout with two flex items and a splitter, the bar created by the splitter to allow the components to be resized proportionately to one another is always white- is there anyway this can be changed through a SASS config?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: Does Ext have any sass variable to style splitter backgrounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/util/_splitter.scss` indicates that it doesn't use a variable

```scss
@mixin extjs-splitter {
    .#{$prefix}splitter {
        .#{$prefix}collapse-el {
            position: absolute;

            cursor: pointer;

            background-color: transparent;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to override it in CSS, or create your own theme.

*CSS*

```css
.x-splitter-vertical {
    background-color: #abc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I added the above but no luck I'm afraid. Incidentally its a vertical split so cursor:pointer suggests this isnt the right css to change (it should be ew-resize)

Comment: Adding div .x-splitter-vertical{background:#HEX;} seems to do the trick

Comment: Of course you can do that in CSS as I mentioned, but you asked about SASS variables, not CSS.

Comment: Now you've added the CSS code from my comment above, I'll accept the answer to help future viewers